# QSqlQuery.record() is always empty

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I'm editing the database in this manner:

```
QSqlQuery query;

query.prepare("UPDATE student "
        "SET name = ? "
        "WHERE id = ?");

QString name = "t"; 
int id = 3;

query.addBindValue(name);
query.addBindValue(id);

query.exec(); // query exec returns true

QSqlRecord record = query.record(); // but the record is empty!
mTableModel->beforeInsert(record);
```

The retrieved record is always empty, but the `QSqlTableModel` still changes! I need the record to be valid because I'm trying to synchronize an sql db with a std::vector.

I'm connecting to the database like this:

```
mDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mDatabase.setDatabaseName("database.db");
mDatabase.open();
```

---

I tried calling `QSqlQuery::clear()`, `QSqlQuery::finish()` but it didn't help. I also tried to open and close the DB, but it also didn't help. What can I do? :\

Comment: You need to link the query to the db, as in `QSqlQuery query(mDatabase);`, otherwise the db is practically untouched, right? Look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-3. Btw, welcome to SO! and Qt is not a pain.

Comment: @Siidheesh, not really. I don't *HAVE* to. the DB you're currently connected to is used if you don't pass in an argument. And like I said, QSqlTableModel that is linked to this DB changed, while the record is invalid. Qt is a pain. xD

Comment: No, ALL the constructors for `QSqlQuery` take at least one argument. So, you have to.

Comment: The answer I gave was wrong, I'm not sure what else could be wrong with the code, try checking if `query.isValid()` is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is not a pain indeed.

All your code is good. The only wrong assumption is that an update request will automatically give you back the updated record. You have to make a new select request on this `id` to get the updates data in a `QSqlRecord`.

```
//[untested]
QSqlQuery select;
select.prepare("SELECT * from student where id = ?");
select.addBindValue(id);

if (select.exec() && select.next()) {
  QSqlRecord record = select.record();
}
```

Comment: Looks like I needed to invoke next() indeed.