# QSqlDatabase::record(const QString &tablename) returns empty record

Tags: c++, qt, qsqldatabase

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998117/qsqlquery-record-is-always-empty) question. I want to get field names of a table using method QSqlDatabase::record(const QString &tablename). But it always returns an empty record. I can query database tables by QSQLQuery properly. My database is a SQL Server database.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should get.

As you are saying SQL server, try with "@yourtablename". I mean to say prepend "@" before your tablename in your QString.

if no luck,

Check your table name. (spaces or additional chars etc..)

Type cast to `QString` (safe side). Or create a `QString` object with table name and pass it.

Trim the QString, before passing it.

Still for some reason if you are not getting the field names, try below steps.

Your `QSqlRecord QSqlDatabase::record(const QString &tablename) const` will return a `QSqlRecord` object

First get the number fields in record

```
int QSqlRecord::count() const
```

Loop the count (ex: using for) and get the **field name** for each index using below function

`QString QSqlRecord::fieldName(int index) const`

**Some pseudo code below: (assuming you have successful connection established, Not compiled and not tested.)**

```
QSqlRecord rec = QSqlDatabase::record("Your table name");

int count = rec.count();

QStringList fieldNames;

For (int i =0; i<count; i++)
{
    fieldNames.push_back(rec.fieldName(i);
}
```

**By Select Query:**

```
QSqlQuery select;
select.prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'");

if (select.exec() && select.next()) {
  QSqlRecord record = select.record();
}
```

Comment: I tried all your hints, but still not working. I get empty from QSqlDatabase::record() and QSqlRecord::count() returns zero.

Comment: hmmm.... did you try something thing like this QString str = "@tablename".

Comment: Can you try by querying select statement, which I added in my answer.

Comment: Yes I tried QString str = "@tablename". But it is not working. By using the QSQLQuery::record() method it is ok and I get field names, but I wonder why QSqlDatabase::record(const QString &tablename) is not working!

Comment: Can you first call "void QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(const QString &name)", before calling the record.My wild guess is "QSqlDatabase::record(const QString &tablename)" unable to find the table?